# Браузер вывел странную страницу. Хотелось бы узнать что это

Tags: веб-программирование, visual-studio-code

Пытался вывести html страницу с помощью плагина Go LIve, в итоге вывело то что находится в левой части экрана. Во время создания сервера находился в открытом на скрине файле. Могу также открывать файлы на этой странице, там лежит то, что написано в тех же файлах что у меня в редакторе. Так же сверху есть строка поиска. Было бы интересно узнать что это за страница и почему она это вывела.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По умолчанию, за [главную страницу сайта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index.html) отвечает файл с названием `index.расширение` или `default.расширение` , если этого файла нет, то там уже зависит от сервера, некоторые выводят ошибку (404 или 403), а некоторые выводят список всех файлов каталога (как у вас).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за ответ, очень благодарен!